# ASP Net Core and Entity Framework Error - A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I with my colleagues couldn't solve a very strange issue.
I created a small project based on .net core 3 and EF 3 (tried also 5 with the same result).
It's a simple API project with connection to MS SQL database.

And when I generate more than 2 parallel requests to my controller, I got exceptions:

- *System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed*.  When I trying to get data from database
  or
- *Cannot access a disposed context instance* when trying to save or update my data.

There is my code:

```
    Startup.CS
    
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddDbContext<IPContext>(
                    options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                },
                    ServiceLifetime.Transient );
                services.AddTransient<IService, MyService>();
                            
            }
 

    IPContext.CS
        public class IPContext : DbContext
            {
                public IPContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
                {
        
                }
        
                public DbSet<IModel> IPData { get; set; }
            }

Controller:
 public async Task<IResult> Get(string param)
        {
            IResult res =  await  _service.GetData(param);
}

-----
MyService.cs
 public class MyService :IService
    {
        private static ILogger<MyService> _logger;
        private static IPContext _context;
        private static IConfiguration _config;
        public MyService( ILogger<MyService> logger, 
            IPContext context, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
            _config = config;
        }
        public async Task<IResult> GetData(string param)
        {
           return await _context.IPData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.param == param);
        }
```

When I run concurrent connections, I got error at this "FirstOrDefauilAsync" operation.
The only solution which allows me to run many concurrent connections is using "Using":

```
using (IPContext _context = new IPContext()) {
                    return await _context.IPData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.param == param);
                }
```

I understand that the problem is somewhere inside Depencency Injection. But I tried changing options at my Startup class to Singletone (which is incorrect, but I tried), I checked other projects where we used the  similar code and which worked correctly. And completely can't understand where I'm wrong.

Maybe somebody can help..

Sincerely
Dmitry

Answer (score 2):

After many experiments with different projects, I found the reason.

I used context as :

```
  private static IPContext _context;
```

But it's wrong. The correct way is

```
  private **readonly** IPContext _context;
```

Changing the access level solved the problem and now I can run  many concurrent requests.

Comment: The problem was not that you didn't have `readonly` in it, but that you had `static` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is not strange at all. One EF database context can run only one database operation at any time. If this operation has finished, you can start another one on the same ED database context. If you need to run two database operations in parallel, you have to use two EF database contexts.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. I have the API controller. It's typical when many clients use it at the same time. So, what I have to do to provide data to all clients? 
According to MS documentation, I have to use "await". I use it.

Comment: For each request from a client, you have to create a new context: `using (IPContext _context = new IPContext())` does the trick!

Comment: OK, maybe I'm wrong.. But there is another ecample:
https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp30/tree/master/DatingApp.API
It's a project from Udemy course. And there everywhere they use the same approach as mine.

Comment: Which file and line(s) of code of this example are you referring to in particular?

Comment: For example
https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp30/blob/master/DatingApp.API/Data/DatingRepository.cs
There are services with database connections similar to mine

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in line 68 of https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp30/blob/master/DatingApp.API/Startup.cs , the DatingRepository is created once for every request. So every request has its own DatingRepository and its own EF database context.

Comment: OK, I do the same
 I used services.AddTransient<IService, MyService>();
Also I tried AddScoped. Right now I checked again with AddScoped. Exception still orrurs..

Comment: In addition, I tried to move my database request directly to controller.
The problem is the same..  So, it seems that something wrong with my Startup class...